# How to write dependency injection for database connection mysqli in php?

Tags: php

I have tried to write to write the dependency injection but the class file is getting an error. How to properly write the database connection class and use it as a dependency injection?. Please check with the following error. How to write the connection once and call it everywhere in php files.

Database.php

```
class Database
{
    private $host ="localhost";
    private $user = "root";
    private $password="xxxx";
    private $db="";
    private $mysqli;


    function __construct($host,$user,$pass,$data) {

        $this->host     = $host;
        $this->user     = $user;
        $this->pass     = $pass;
        $this->data     = $data;
        $this->mysqli   = new mysqli($this->host, $this->user, $this->pass, $this->data);
    }

    public function query($query)
    {
        return $this->mysqli->query($query);
    }
}
```

Dummy.php

```
require_once("../apitest/database.php");

class Dummy
{
    protected $db;

    function __construct(Database $db)
    {
        $this->db = $db;
    }

    function get_test_yada(){
        return $this->db->mysqli->query("SELECT test FROM test")->fetch_object()->test;
    }
}
```

Code:

```
$test = new Dummy();
echo $test->get_test_yada();
```

Error

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to
>   Dummy::__construct() must be an instance of Database, none given,
>   called in /var/www/html/apitest/index.php on line 19 and defined in
>   /var/www/html/apitest/index.php:8\nStack trace:\n#0
>   /var/www/html/apitest/index.php(19): Dummy->__construct()\n#1 {main}\n
>   thrown in /var/www/html/apitest/index.php on line 8

Comment: What's the error you have?

Comment: where to write the config details

Comment: It looks like you forget declare `$db` variable in your `Dummy` class.

Comment: @OlegNurutdinov [Mon Nov 26 17:57:25.636338 2018] [:error] [pid 13751] [client ::1:40700] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Dummy::__construct() must be an instance of Database, none given, called in /var/www/html/apitest/index.php on line 19 and defined in /var/www/html/apitest/index.php:8\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/html/apitest/index.php(19): Dummy->__construct()\n#1 {main}\n  thrown in /var/www/html/apitest/index.php on line 8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not passing Database instance when you're trying to instantiate Dummy object.

It should look like this:

```
<?php

$host = 'localhost';
$user = 'root';
$pass = '';
$dbname = 'db';

$db = new Database($host,$user,$pass,$dbname);
$test = new Dummy($db);
echo $test->get_test_yada();
```

Comment: How to instantiate at once as dependency injection and use it everywhere

Comment: It depends on you application architecture, you may do it on various ways. The easiest way is to make $db variable global.

Comment: But this is the way how you should instantiate it. All other things you should create new ticket and we will provide you appropriate answer.

Comment: @AleksandarRakić but global variables are consired bad pratice. Another approach would be making the database class a singleton. But this is consired an anti-pattern. Therefore I'm confused how to ensure that every method use the same database connection because there should be only one database connection for the entire execution lifetime. I'm sick tired of reading something like "use dependency injection..." without explaining how to do it for objects that should only have one instance and how to do it properly.

Answer (score 0):

where this properties `$data` and `$db`?

```
class Database
{
    private $host ="localhost";
    private $user = "root";
    private $password="xxx";
    private $db="";
    private $mysqli;


    function __construct($host,$user,$pass,$data) {

        $this->host     = $host;
        $this->user     = $user;
        $this->pass     = $pass;
        $this->db       = $data;
        $this->mysqli   = new mysqli($this->host, $this->user, $this->pass, $this->db);
    }
}

class Dummy 
{
    protected $db;

    function __construct(Database $db)
    {
       $this->db = $db;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This error means you need to pass to your `Dummy` object a `Database` **object** as a parameter

> Argument 1 passed to Dummy::__construct() must be an instance of
>   Database

I think you have the wrong idea about how Dependency Injection works an I strongly encourage you to read some articles about it before proceeding.

[Wikipedia Dependency Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection)

[Simple tutorial about Dependency Injection in tutplus](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/dependency-injection-huh--net-26903)

[Dependency Injection (DI) Container in PHP](https://medium.com/tech-tajawal/dependency-injection-di-container-in-php-a7e5d309ccc6) *Cool article from Medium*

[PHP-DI](http://php-di.org/doc/understanding-di.html)  *A php Dependency Injection Container package*